# TKInter Frame formatting not working

Tags: python, tkinter

Quick question everyone. I apologize for how simple it is but why is it that when I add something to a frame like a checkbutton or label the formatting of the frame goes away and it's size snaps to whatever it is I put inside it?

Thank you,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply how it's designed to work. It's a very powerful feature. You worry about what widgets you want in a frame and thinter can take care of doing all the math to make sure everything fits.